# Ambiguity while using italic font

Tags: discussion, feature-request, markdown

While posting a question I saw help text which appears at right hand side of the screen titled *"How to Format"*.

It instructed to write in *italic* use _ (It works!), but when using *italic* option provided at top (named Emphasis) it surrounds my text with *.

Both seemed pretty the same to me.

My question is why there are two options ( _ and *) for the same task?

**EDIT1:** Now I know how it works. But why it doesn't appear in the help that appears when while writing a post? It would have been more clearer.

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is: because it's specified in the Markdown standards, just like you can both `**` and `__` (two underscores) for bold text.

As for why Markdown adopted this convention: in the past (pre-HTML era) people used both * and _ to [emphasize texts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emphasis_(typography)). And within HTML, the element signifying emphasis, [`<em>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em), is usually rendered in italics, just like [pre-computer typography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italic_type).

> But why it doesn't appear in the help that appears when while writing a post? It would have been more clearer.

There are *even more* options to write italic text, like `<em>text</em>` and `<i>text</i>`. More options usually make it *less* clear. Full documentation can be found elsewhere, e.g. in the ['inline help'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9dmS.png) and the [Advanced help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: I just noticed that a user can also use ** and __ for bold text. Then why it is not mentioned in help text (which appears at right)?

Comment: It *is* mentioned here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: @Glorfindel I think OP means it doesn't appear in the help that appears when pressing "help" while commenting\writing a post

Comment: Ah, I finally see which help text you mean. It's not [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9dmS.png), it's the one on the Ask Question page. (I don't visit that very often :)). I don't know why, but I guess the line would be too long.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to confuse It is implemented in markdown.

You're talking about this line in the right side of ask page

> `_italic_ or **bold**`

I believe it is written in such a way to avoid confuse because if they added `*italic*` it may look confusing.

also `_` and `__` are confusing.

But both of them will work fine.

enclosing a string with either `_` or `*` will produce the same result.

Eg.

- `_italic text_` => *italic text*
- `*italic text*` => *italic text*

Also this is same to bold

- `__bold text__` => **bold text**
- `**bold text**` => **bold text**

Alternatively you can use the corresponding HTML tags (Stack Exchange support some basic Markups too)

- `<i>italic text</i>` => *italic text*
- `<b>bold text</b>` => **bold text**

When you click on the button in the toolbox or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>, it will insert `*` for italic and `**` for bold.

Comment: Now I know how it works. But why it doesn't appear in the help that appears when  while writing a post? It would have been more clearer.

Comment: @NiladriSekharBasu because no one put it there. maybe a [tag:feature-request] for it has merit. I dunno...

Comment: already in the answer. `_` and `__` may confuse some people also `*` and `**` will do so for some people

Answer (score 0):

the Stack Exchange network uses Markdown to format stuff (answers,questions,tag wikis etc.) and italics in markdown are created with `*` on both sides of what you're styling. (no spaces between the letters and the `*`. i.e. * this won't style* because of the space).

However markdown also allows you to use _ instead of *, anywhere. e.g: **this is bold** , but with _ and not *. So it's the language used to style fonts.

You can find a markdown cheat sheet [here](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#emphasis)